# Measure of the set where a trigonometric polynomial with zero mean is non-negative

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, trigonometric-series

Suppose $f$ is a real trigonometric polynomial of degree $N$ with constant term $0$.  What lower bounds can we place on the measure $\mu$ of the set $\{ t \in S^1 : f(t) \geq 0 \}$, independent of the coefficients of the polynomial?

Using Parseval to put a lower bound on $\max |f|$, and putting a crude upper bound on $|f'|$, I can get a lower bound on $\mu$ of order $N^{-3/2}$.  But I'm guessing that one can probably do significantly better.

Just to fix notation, I'm putting the factors of $2 \pi$ inside the trig functions, so that $f$ has period $1$ and $S^1$ has length $1$.

---

Added in response to comment:

Let $C$ be the sum of the absolute values of the coefficients of $f$, and let $D$ be the sum of the squares of the coefficients.  Let $M = \max |f|$.  By Parseval we have $M \geq \alpha D^{1/2}$ for some constant $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}_+$.  Then by the QM-AM inequality we get $M \geq \alpha C N^{-1/2}$.  Trivially we have $|f'| \leq \pi C N$.

Suppose $\max f = M$, and that this max is attained at $0$.  The interval about $0$ on which $f \geq 0$ then has length at least

$$2 \frac{\max f}{ \max |f'|}$$

(assuming $f$ isn't identically zero), which is at least

$$\frac{2 \alpha}{\pi} N^{-3/2}$$

Otherwise, $\max f < M$ and the above calculation shows that the graph of $f$ has a triangle of area at least

$$\frac{M \alpha}{\pi} N^{-3/2}$$

lying below the $t$-axis.  Since $f$ integrates to zero, the integral of the non-negative part of $f$ must cancel out this contribution.  Since $f < M$ we see that $f$ must be non-negative on a set of length at least

$$l := \frac{\alpha}{\pi} N^{-3/2}$$

So in either case we get a lower bound of $l$.

Comment: So suppose we have a really simple case $f(x)=-\sin^2x$. The only point of $[0,2\pi)$ at which it is non-negative is 0, which has measure 0? Oh, wait you do not allow powers. Only terms like $\sin nx,\cos nx$. Is that right?

Comment: @almagest Yes, only terms like $\sin nx$ and $\cos nx$ for $1 \leq n \leq N$ are allowed.

Comment: Of course, bearing in mind the convention I claimed to be using in the question, I should have written "terms like $\sin 2 \pi nx$ and $\cos 2 \pi nx$".

Comment: @Thursday Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Here's a proof that the measure can be $O(N^{-1+\epsilon})$, for any $\epsilon>0$. Consider $f(x)=(\sin(\pi nt)/\sin(\pi t))^m$ where $m$ is a fixed even integer. Up to a constant, this is a power of Fejer kernel (with Jackson kernel as a special case). The mean value of $f$ is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $m-1$. Thus, the set of interest is $\{f\ge cn^{m-1}\}$. Since $|f(x)|\le 1/\sin^m(\pi t)$, this set is  contained in an  interval of length $O(n^{(1-m)/m})$ around $0$. // So, your estimate is not far from optimal. Maybe if you posted its derivation, someone would suggest an improvement?

Comment: @Thursday I'll modify the question to show the derivation.  How are you evaluating the mean value of $f$?

Comment: @Jez For the purpose of commenting: by checking a few values of $n$ with CAS and plugging into OEIS. :) Seriously: the Fourier  coefficients are a convolution of $[1,\dots,1]$ with itself $m$ times. So it ends up being a number of ways to represent $0$ as a sum of $m$ integers of size up to $n$, which is roughly $n^m / n$.

Comment: @Thursday Thanks for another useful comment and for tweaking the title and formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same upper bound as Thursday.

An easy lower bound is $\frac1{N+1}$: it follows from the identity
$$ f(x)+f\left(x+\frac1{N+1}\right)+f\left(x+\frac2{N+1}\right)+\ldots+f\left(x+\frac{N}{N+1}\right)=0. $$

Comment: Thanks very much!  That's really neat; far cleaner and stronger than what I'd done.

Comment: Thanks. Thanks for the +50 as well. But I do not consider this answer complete...

Comment: Ideally of course we would like a family of examples that showed your bound (or an improvement on it) is sharp.  Should I un-accept your answer to get more attention?

Comment: OK. I do not mind. :-)